# Gstreamer custom plugin registration issue

Tags: c, plugins, gstreamer, pipeline, gobject

I just started to use gstreamer and I want to know how to register a plugin that I wrote.  Of course, I have followed the *Plugin Writer's Guide* and used the `make_element` command to build my plugin. Now, I want to test it in a basic pipe line using the `gst-launch` command.

The problem is that I don't know how to register my plugin.

I've tried the `--gst-plugin-path` option with the path of the .c and .h files, but I get this:

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline

I am using gstreamer-0.10.

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v solve my problem by upgrading to 1.0 but I also had to change the installation path in the  "configure" folder.